# steady-state response

Tags: filters

Why does the response of this system evaluated in $0.25$ such that
$$H_p(0.25)=\frac{1}{1-0.5e^{-j2\pi /4}}=\frac{1}{1+j0.5}$$

equal $0.89943\angle-26.6º$?

Comment: You shall better learn some complex algebra. That's a primary notion of Electrical Engineering. Specifically focus on complex exponential $e^{j\phi}$ , polar to rectengular conversion as $re^{j\phi} = r\cos(\phi) + j r\sin(\phi)$ and rational expression manipulations such as conjugation of the denumerator to convert a rational expression to rectengular form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is why $\frac{1}{1+j0.5} = 0.89\angle-26.6º$. Let's write this complex number in a better way:

$$\frac{1}{1+j0.5}=\frac{1}{1+j0.5}\cdot \frac{1-j0.5}{1-j0.5}=\frac{1-j0.5}{1^2+0.5^2}=\frac{1}{1.25}+j\left(-\frac{0.5}{1.25}\right)=0.8+j(-0.4)$$

This means that the radius of this complex number is

$$|0.8+j(-0.4)|=\sqrt{0.8^2+0.4^2}=0.89$$
And its angle is $$\angle0.8+j(-0.4)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-0.4}{0.8}\right)=-26.6º$$

Comment: Thank you bro. you are the best. 10000000000000 thanks (Y)